# Promise.all resolved even one of my promises array I expect to rejected

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have an array of promises that contain simple api url for fetch a github users. I try to make it failed with putting a wrong url in one of my value of array, but it always resolve?

Here i provide a link to my test case
https://jsbin.com/lapibalate/edit?js,console

```
let urlMap = [
  {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/andreepratama27',
  },
  {
    url: 'https://apiiiiiii.github.com/users/rizalfakhri12'
  }
]

let promises = urlMap.map(v => fetch(v))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(res => console.log('RESOLVED'))
  .catch(err => console.log("REJECTED"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your doing a fetch not towards the URLs you specified, but towards `[object Object]` on your current URL (as the `v` property is an object, not a string). Change the map to read the `url` property and it will be rejected:

```
let promises = urlMap.map(v => fetch(v.url))
```

Complete example with changes:

```js
let urlMap = [
  {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/andreepratama27',
  },
  {
    url: 'https://apiiiiiii.github.com/users/rizalfakhri12'
  }
]

let promises = urlMap.map(v => fetch(v.url))

Promise.all(promises)
  .then(res => console.log('RESOLVED'))
  .catch(err => console.log("REJECTED"))
```

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst Interesting. I didn't actually know that, but it's weird because when I run the snippet in my post it said `REJECTED`. Chrome on OS X, that means they don't follow spec?

Comment: Its been rejected due to cors issue not because of 404. So using correct url wont help. 404 still resolves the promise.

Comment: Thanks! I forget to put the property that I want to get the data from it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

> The fetch specification differs from jQuery.ajax() in two main ways:
>
> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

So thats why.